# Create multi-dimensional array so objects are read in same order as created

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to create a multi-dimensional array using the func below which I prefer as it is easier to read rather than a very long string. The problem is when its saved to `UserDefaults.standard` location then when array is read the pairs of objects are NOT returned in the same order as created. Is this possible or am I asking too much?

Here is the code I am using and the output is below :-

```
func testDatabase() {
    var defaultArray = [[String: Any]]()
    defaultArray.removeAll()
    defaultArray.append(["item": "First item", "quantity": 1])
    defaultArray.append(["item": "Second item", "quantity": 2])
    defaultArray.append(["item": "Third item", "quantity": 3])
    defaultArray.append(["item": "Fourth item", "quantity": 4])
    defaultArray.append(["item": "Fifth item", "quantity": 5])
    preferences.set(defaultArray, forKey: "defaultArray_Prefs")
    defaultArray = (preferences.array(forKey: "defaultArray_Prefs") as? [[String: Any]])!
    print("defaultArray = \(defaultArray)")
}
```

Output :-

```
defaultArray = [["quantity": 1, "item": First item], ["item": Second item, "quantity": 2], ["quantity": 3, "item": Third item], ["quantity": 4, "item": Fourth item], ["item": Fifth item, "quantity": 5]]
```

Comment: [Edit] and tag the language

Comment: Because you are assigning new values to your array and you don't know how `preferences.array` reads -- order wise -- values.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered by definition. As the values are accessed by keys the order doesn't matter.

Comment: What isn't clear about the output? Isn't that the expected outcome?

Comment: I am trying to output the information as a text file for printing on a laptop (I am attaching it to an email) and I thought I was not specifying the array correctly. Is there a method to reorder the keys / values because in my app I have 5 keys.

Comment: @Andy is the issue that `quantity` and `item` are not returning in the same order?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what the problem is.